# How do you pass in null values for Number in a function parameter?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a function that I would like to pass in null for the parameters so that the default param values get picked up but it doesn't seem to like null, undefined or NaN.

Here is my function:

```
function myFunction(value:Number = .5, value2:Number = .6):Number {
   return value;
}
```

and then later:

```
var result = myFunction(null, 10);
trace(result); // 0

var result = myFunction(NaN, 10);
trace(result); // NaN

var result = myFunction(undefined, 10);
trace(result); // NaN
```

How do I get it to default to .5?

Comment: Is there an equivalent to what C# calls Nullable<> a type like Number?

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't heard of that in AS3.

Comment: I dont know the first thing about actionscript but anyway:
What hapens if you pass value by name:
var result = myFunction(value2: 10); and omit value?

Comment: AS3 doesn't support that but it would be really nice. It has been brought up for ASNext.

Comment: what if you write: result = myFunction( , 10);

Comment: optional arguments are basically syntactical sugar for invoking a function where `arguments.length` is less that `function.length`. If you have specified a value when invoking the method, then that is it's value. Your problem would probably better be solved by not using optional arguments, but pass in an `options` object. `myFunction({value2:10});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call your function without passing parameters, you should get the default value as you expect. In your example, the default value is only used if a value is not passed at all.

```
function myFunction(value:Number = .5, value2:Number = .6):Number {
   return value;
}

var result = myFunction();
trace( result ) // 0.5
```

If you are wanting to pass a second parameter but not the first, then you might have to consider an alternative approach.

Vars typed to 'Number' in AS3 cannot have the value null and will be converted to NaN automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you are doing is [Function Overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) and that is **not** supported in AS3.
However, you could mimic overloading by using the wildcard type.

```
function myFunction(value:*= .5, value2:Number = .6):Number {
   return value;
}
```

But your default value probably won't be assigned/accessible.
I would strongly suggest you redesign this though because this has code smell written all over it, and will come back to haunt you later on.

Answer (score -1):

```
function myFunction(value:Number = .5, value2:Number = .6):Number
{
    if (isNaN(value)) value = .5;
    return value;
}

var result = myFunction(NaN,10);
trace(result); //0.5
```

What exactly are you trying to do? Surely there has to be a better approach.

Comment: If you're going to down an answer, at least leave a reason why, coward

Comment: I wanted to know how to pass in null values for a method,. Saying there's a better approach is not a helpful answer esp when passing in null for other types (besides number) is ok. For some reason there's no option for that in AS3. I regret down voting it because it is useful. Unfortunately, it's locked. Edit your answer to include, "you can't do that so here's the alternative" and I'll remove the down vote.